# Installing Alpha Vantage in Conda

Tags: python, pip, package, finance, alpha-vantage

I was looking to try out [Alpha Vantage's API](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alpha_vantage) in Python, but I'd like to install it using Anaconda rather than pip.  I'm fairly new to conda however.

I searched for alpha_vantage in conda

```
conda search alpha_vantage
```

and it says alpha_vantage is not available on my channels.  Is there a way to find a channel that has it?  I sort of thought that is what the search would be for.

Comment: How about building it yourself? `conda skeleton pypi alpha_vantage`, then `conda build alpha_vantage`. You can then upload it to your own channel at anaconda.org and install via `conda install alpha_vantage -c mychannel`.

Comment: glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I could do the same with my latest issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49615395/conda-install-of-pykalman-package-reverting-python-to-version-3-5 but the skeleton install fails on some weird permission error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just built the alpha_vantage 2.0 and uploaded to anaconda.org. Its build for python 3.6 on macOS. You may download it using my channel:

```
conda install alpha_vantage -c hoishing
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm on win64, but it looks like since I asked this question someone else has built a win64 version.

Comment: @rhaskett: can you point us to the win64 version?  I can't find it