# Conda Install of PyKalman Package Reverting Python to Version 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, package, conda

I'm still learning how to use Anaconda package manager.  I'm trying to install [PyKalman](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pykalman) through Conda.  Conda seems happy to do so but then tries to downgrade all my packages to Python 3.5 from Python 3.6.

For example:

```
pandas:        0.22.0-py36h6538335_0      --> 0.22.0-py35_0     conda-forge
```

I'll need 3.6 for later packages I need to install (i.e. [blpapi](https://anaconda.org/mbonix/blpapi)).

Is there a good workaround here?

Comment: This is because the package is only available for Python 3.5: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pykalman/files You can file an issue on the feedstock: https://github.com/conda-forge/pykalman-feedstock to have someone rebuild it

Comment: The other workaround is to build the package yourself, it isn't that difficult... you can just install conda-build to your base environment, clone the feedstock, cd to the feedstock directory and type `conda build recipe` then `conda install --use-local pykalman`

Comment: ok I left feedback and I followed https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html which although I had a number of weird errors along the way seems to have worked when I copied the bz2 over manually.

Comment: If you write up a quick answer I'll give you credit.